# [ASOC][tlv320aic3110] Error resetting registers and error 16 (device or resource busy)

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, alsa, device-tree, i2s

I am having an issue with the tlv320aic3110 codec. I get these two errors during boot up in my embedded device:

```
[   10.079068] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: Unable to sync registers 0x1d-0x1d. -6
[   10.161668] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: Failed to restore cache: -6
```

According to the datasheet, 0x1d can be "Table 7-69. Page 0 / Register 29 (0x1D): Codec Interface Control 2" or "Table 7-136. Page 1 / Register 1 (0x01) Through Page 1 / Register 29 (0x1D): Reserved".

After about a minute, there are also these errors:

```
[   66.858820] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: ASoC: error at snd_soc_component_update_bits on tlv320aic31xx-codec.0-0018: -16
[   66.943057] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: ASoC: error at snd_soc_component_update_bits on tlv320aic31xx-codec.0-0018: -16
[   67.092200] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: ASoC: POST_PMU: HPL Driver event failed: -16
[   67.383700] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: ASoC: error at soc_component_read_no_lock on tlv320aic31xx-codec.0-0018: -16
[   67.482291] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: ASoC: error at soc_component_read_no_lock on tlv320aic31xx-codec.0-0018: -16
[   67.545386] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: ASoC: POST_PMU: SPL ClassD event failed: -16
[   67.823211] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: ASoC: error at soc_component_read_no_lock on tlv320aic31xx-codec.0-0018: -16
[   67.895536] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: ASoC: error at soc_component_read_no_lock on tlv320aic31xx-codec.0-0018: -16
```

And finally, after suspend/resume, I get these last errors:

```
[ 5981.210062] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: ASoC: POST_PMD: HPL Driver event failed: -16
[ 5981.210103] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: ASoC: POST_PMD: SPL ClassD event failed: -16
[ 5981.210170] v1v8_ao: Underflow of regulator enable count
[ 5981.210184] Failed to disable DVDD: -EINVAL
[ 5981.223267] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: Unable to sync registers 0x1d-0x1d. -6
[ 5981.223303] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: Failed to restore cache: -6
[ 5981.233551] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: aic31xx_wait_bits: Failed! 0x25 was 0xc1855ddb expected 0x20 (-16, 0x20, 0 us)
[ 5981.233591] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: ASoC: POST_PMU: HPL Driver event failed: -1
[ 5981.233669] tlv320aic31xx-codec 0-0018: ASoC: POST_PMU: SPL ClassD event failed: -16
```

Here are all the relevant parts of our device tree:

```
/ {
    sound0: sound@0 {
        compatible = "simple-audio-card";
        simple-audio-card,name = "Sound";
        simple-audio-card,widgets =
            "Microphone", "Microphone Jack",
            "Headphone", "Headphone Jack",
            "Speaker", "Speaker";
        simple-audio-card,routing =
            "MIC1LP", "Microphone Jack",
            "MIC1RP", "Microphone Jack",
            "MIC1LP", "MICBIAS",
            "MIC1RP", "MICBIAS",
            "Headphone Jack", "HPL",
            "Headphone Jack", "HPR",
            "Speaker", "SPL",
            "Speaker", "SPR";
        simple-audio-card,format = "i2s";
        simple-audio-card,bitclock-master = <&sound0_master>;
        simple-audio-card,frame-master = <&sound0_master>;
        simple-audio-card,bitclock-inversion;
        simple-audio-card,convert-rate = <48000>;

        sound0_master: simple-audio-card,cpu {
            sound-dai = <&i2s1>;
            system-clock-frequency = <12000000>;
        };

        simple-audio-card,codec {
            sound-dai = <&codec>;
            system-clock-frequency = <12000000>;
        };
    };
};

&pinctrl {
    codec_pins_a: codec_pins_a {
        pins1 {
            pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('H', 2, GPIO)>; /* AUDIO_PWR_EN1 */
        };

        pins2 {
            pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('C', 0, AF6)>,   /* CODEC_I2S1_SDO */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('A', 6, AF5)>,   /* CODEC_I2S1_SDI */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('B', 1, AF5)>,   /* CODEC_I2S1_BITCLK / I2S1_CK */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('B', 0, AF5)>,   /* I2S1_MCK */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('A', 4, AF5)>;   /* CODEC_I2S1_WORDCLK / I2S1_WS */
        };
    };

    codec_sleep_pins_a: codec_sleep_pins_a {
        pins {
            pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('H', 2, ANALOG)>,    /* AUDIO_PWR_EN1 */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('C', 0, ANALOG)>,    /* CODEC_I2S1_SDO */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('A', 6, ANALOG)>,    /* CODEC_I2S1_SDI */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('B', 1, ANALOG)>,    /* CODEC_I2S1_BITCLK / I2S1_CK */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('B', 0, ANALOG)>,    /* I2S1_MCK */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('A', 4, ANALOG)>;    /* CODEC_I2S1_WORDCLK / I2S1_WS */
        };
    };
};

&i2s1 {
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names =  "default", "sleep";
    pinctrl-0 = <&codec_pins_a>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&codec_sleep_pins_a>;  /* Sleep pins */

    clock-names = "pclk", "i2sclk", "x8k", "x11k";
    clocks = <&rcc SPI1>,
             <&rcc SPI1_K>,
             <&scmi_clk CK_SCMI_PLL3_Q>,
             <&scmi_clk CK_SCMI_PLL3_R>;
};

&i2c1 {
    pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2c1_pins_a>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&i2c1_sleep_pins_a>;
    i2c-scl-rising-time-ns = <96>;
    i2c-scl-falling-time-ns = <3>;
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    status = "okay";
    /* spare dmas for other usage */
    /delete-property/dmas;
    /delete-property/dma-names;

    codec: codec@18 {
        compatible = "ti,tlv320aic3110";
        reg = <0x18>;
        #sound-dai-cells = <0>;
        status = "okay";

        reset-gpios = <&gpiof 6 (GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW | GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN)>;

        ai31xx-micbias-vg = <MICBIAS_2_0V>;

        /* Regulators */
        HPVDD-supply = <&scmi_v3v3_sw>; /* 3V3_CODEC */
        SPRVDD-supply = <&v5v0_ao>; /* 5V0_CODEC */
        SPLVDD-supply = <&v5v0_ao>; /* 5V0_CODEC */
        AVDD-supply = <&scmi_v3v3_sw>;  /* 3V3_CODEC */
        IOVDD-supply = <&scmi_v3v3_sw>; /* 3V3_CODEC */
        DVDD-supply = <&scmi_v1v8_periph>;  /* 1V8_CODEC */
    };
};
```

I have been trying to find a solution for a few days but I haven't been able to find anything important. Is there anything I could do to maybe get closer to the root cause of these errors? Has anyone seen something like this before?

Kernel version is 5.15.131.

I believe the problem is likely to be in the device tree, but I have no idea what I could change to fix it.

Let me know if you need any other information from me that might help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kernel version? If you can't rephrase this issue as a programming issue, then this post is likely to be closed.

Comment: @sawdust it's version 5.15.131 and I've updated the post to add my suspicion of where I think the issue is. I could be wrong, but I think a change in the device tree is likely to fix this, I just don't know what to change.